# Git or Git version Control Master and Branches for existed Projects

Tags: git

I have more than 6 version of PHP System in different Hosts for different Clients all are the same but some files of them have differences . So I'm struggling because if I Add new feature , I need to add them for all the systems in all the hosts .
Is there any chance that I can use Git or Git version Control without affecting those systems or deploy them again in their hosts .
I need to have for example : one host which is the master and when I make changes I can apply that change for the other branches after configuring them to accept .
Last I need like roadmap which I can follow to accomplish this scenario ?
any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of differences there are for each host. That may influence your decision. If it is simply config files, you may have them all in one branch and just deploy providing specific configs for each host. Maybe even have template config with parameters passed from the deployment tool ,e.g. Jenkins.

If you have multiple different changes of different nature, then it is better to use branches, it might be even the only way. Unless in the code you will start putting switches(you don't want to go that road). Have a look at  [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) which prime goal is to be able to maintain different versions/releases and have clean workflow for porting changes to all of the versions. Per custom project/host you would have a dedicated branch (host/host1) originated from master or develop. You may have even a dedicated branch that is similar to multiple hosts, you would call it something like maintenance/v1.1.1. and then you would branch from it the host branches.

Each solution has advantages and disadvantages but can offer help for your specific needs.